# Amazon AWS API call in React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to an AWS service through an API call from React using fetch().This is the call code (**** is a censored content):

```
  fetch("https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bot/****/alias/****/user/****/text", {
      method: "POST",
      body: "inputText: hi",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Host": "runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "X-Amz-Date": "20181229T190205Z",
        "Authorization": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=*****/20181229/us-east-1/lex/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=*****************************************",
        "Content-Length": "27"
      }
    })
```

The same API call with the same headers works with Postman app in chrome and returns a valid response.

When calling this API with fetch though, I am getting an error :

```
 message: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."
```

This happens although I am using the same content of headers as the API call from postman which should be good for 5 min without recalculating the signature based on a new date.

One thing I noticed is that the header "Host" doesn't appear on the request in the developer tools -> Network tab on chrome.

It might relate to the problem ? , I can't figure out why it doesn't appear there because I am clearly setting this header.
The following is the request headers I do see(There is message at the top saying:"Provisional headers are shown"):

```
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=***************/20181229/us-east-1/lex/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=************************
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
X-Amz-Date: 20181229T190205Z
```

Comment: Host is a forbidden header and isn't allowed to be set programmatically; it's added in the request by user agent.

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule how can I see what it does send as a "host" header ?, it doesn't appear in the request headers

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before.  I can't remember which one of these fixed it but here's two things to try:

1. Don't use the same headers from Postman, they might be single-use.  Generate your own sigv4 from the front-end.
2. Make sure you're sending your date in UTC time.  I've had similar issues where my CI/CD tests would fail since the docker image's node env was calculating the time based on  different time zone.

Comment: I tried to signing it with a node package that do that, unfortunately I am getting the same error (the X amz date generated automatically by the package methods in UTC time).  Though the headers from postman seems to be multi use for some period of time. I tried reposting the same headers in postman by unchecking the option to generate the AWS signature and the same headers worked for up to 5 mins but not from react , that's why I am thinking there something in the way

Comment: you may be sending too much info - take everything out of your headers except `Authorization` - then add back `Content-Type` and date.  The signature might be correct but AWS isn't receiving what's expected